# MDX Crossjoin Region and Country and grand total

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I need to join two hierarchies, `Region` and `Country`. From our Cube I have to get a result consisting of 1 region and 2 countries. This is what i've done so far:

```
SET [RegionSet] AS 
  {
     [Stores].[Region].&[EUROPE]
  }

SET [CountrySet] AS 
  {
     [Stores].[Country].&[Japan]&[APAC]
    ,[Stores].[Country].&[China]&[APAC]
  }


NON EMPTY
  (
   {
    [RegionSet]
  , [Stores].[Region].[All]
   }
  ) 
* (
   {
    [CountrySet]
  , [Stores].[Country].[All]
   }
  )
    ON ROWS
```

The MSD result is following:

[image: Resulting table]

But I want to list the region and countries in one column without the *All* entries and add a grand total to the last row. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you had a multi-level user hierarchy called `[Geography]` as part of the `[Stores]` dimension then I think it would be trivial:

```
SET [RegionCountrySet] AS 
  {
     [Stores].[Geography].[Region].&[EUROPE]
    ,[Stores].[Geography].[Country].&[Japan]&[APAC]
    ,[Stores].[Geography].[Country].&[China]&[APAC]
  }
```

...but you can create custom aggregated members. Then use the created members on rows:

1. Pick a unused hierarchy to "host" your new members in. I will assume you have a `[Languages]` dimension. The new members are added as children to the `[All]` member of your chosen hierarchy.
2. Create tuples from the targets including the hosts `[All]` member in each of the tuples.

Like this

```
MEMBER [Languages].[Language].[All].[EUROPE] AS
    (
       [Languages].[Language].[All]
      ,[Stores].[Region].&[EUROPE]
    )
MEMBER [Languages].[Language].[All].[Japan] AS
    (
       [Languages].[Language].[All]
      ,[Stores].[Country].&[Japan]&[APAC]
    )  
MEMBER [Languages].[Language].[All].[China] AS
    (
       [Languages].[Language].[All]
      ,[Stores].[Country].&[China]&[APAC]
    )  
SET [S1] AS
   {
     [Languages].[Language].[All].[EUROPE]
    ,[Languages].[Language].[All].[Japan] 
    ,[Languages].[Language].[All].[China]
   }
MEMBER [Languages].[Language].[All].[Grand Total] AS
    Aggregate([S1])
SET [S2] AS
   {
     [Languages].[Language].[All].[EUROPE]
    ,[Languages].[Language].[All].[Japan] 
    ,[Languages].[Language].[All].[China]
    ,[Languages].[Language].[All].[Grand Total]
   }
```

Then in the script try this

```
 [S2] ON ROWS
```

Comment: No problem. Good news (you can mark it as the answer if you like ... you also gain reputation when you mark answers as correct)